# How to pass selected image from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I want to pass the single Image from one `Fragment` to another `Fragment`, where the Images are placed in `GridView` of one `Fragment` and have to set them as background of `FrameLayout` contained in another `Fragment`,,
Thanks,,

Comment: pass the resource id from fragment to fragment using the associated activity. Use a interface as a callback to the activity

Comment: Pass the resource id through bundle to another fragment.             Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("index", resouce_id);
f.setArguments(args);  and access the arguments getArguments().getInt("index", 0);

Comment: But how can I get resource id of image from GridView???

Comment: How you are setting images to gridview?

Comment: @Dasari Using ImageAdapter..

Comment: you mean from gallery you are accessing the images and setting to the gridview?

Comment: In ImageAdapter also u have to set image resouce to image view like         imageView.setImageResource(resourceId); The resource id you have to pass to the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Try This , call this at setOnItemClickListener

```
Fragment fragment = new ImageFullScreen();
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putInt("selected_image", position);
fragment.setArguments(bun);
if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

}

add this at second Fragment ,

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int position = bundle.getInt("selected_image");;
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+position, 1).show();
Drawable image  =getResources().getDrawable(WallPaperoneFragment.imagefield.get(position));imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass image url fragment to another fragment as argument..
pass as
`

```
another_Fragment fr = new another_Fragment();
 Bundle bun = new Bundle();
 bun.putString("selected_image", image_url);
 fr.setArguments(bun);`
```

and get value as `String image_url=getArguments().getString("selected_image");` in anothe_fragment`

or use interface to communicate