# How to send image from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I read these but an error persists:

[How to pass selected image from one fragment to another fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772039/how-to-pass-selected-image-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

[Passing image from one fragment to a another fragment and display image in that fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847634/passing-image-from-one-fragment-to-a-another-fragment-and-display-image-in-that/34847883)

I have created an activity which is transferring data and image from one fragment to another, data is parsing successfully but when I am sending image it says

> 2021-05-16 04:08:52.127 26026-26026/com.example.mcqapp E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:11600: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is my code for fragment first

```
if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        path_New = filePath.getPath();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
bundle.putString("image",path_New);
second mfragment=new second();
mfragment.setArguments(bundle);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, mfragment).commit();
```

Code in second fragment to receive image:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String imagePath = bundle.getString("image");


Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright ,I solved it, i converted uri to string and then in second fragment i converted String to

```
urifilePath = data.getData();
String path = filePath.toString();
bundle.putString("image",path);
```

Second Fragment

```
String imagePath = bundle.getString("image");
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
```